# Oracle SQL Query to identify unique email addresses associated with multiple account IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

Still learning SQL, and I'm having some trouble creating a query that will return a list of email addresses & account IDs when the email is associated with multiple accounts.

The server is Oracle SQL, and I'm working on a single table, "EMAIL" and two fields "UID & "EMAIL_ADDRESS."

I only want to include emails and account numbers when the same email is listed on more than one account ID. Account IDs can have multiple emails, and the same email can be listed multiple times on the same account ID. That is OK. So, I want to exclude those results, which is where I'm running into trouble.

I have a query that currently returns the number of account IDs an email is associated with, when it is associated with more than one account. However, I'm having trouble converting that to a list where I can see the account ID numbers.

The query I'm currently using is

```
SELECT COUNT(EMAIL.UID), EMAIL.EMAIL_ADDRESS
FROM EMAIL
GROUP BY EMAIL.EMAIL_ADDRESS 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EMAIL.UID) > 1
```

This returns a list like:

```
Count of UID      EMAIL_ADDRESS
2                 asmith@...
3                 bjones@...
5                 cbaker@...
```

What I need is:

```
UID               EMAIL_ADDRESS
67890             asmith@...
75236             asmith@...
15689             bjones@...
56748             bjones@...
89523             bjones@...
98542             cbaker@...
00245             cbaker@...
etc, etc          etc, etc
```

I also need to have this ordered by email address so that alike emails are listed together.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Put your current query in a sub-query. Join table with that sub-query.

Comment: You're not that far. Once you have the list of emails, you only need to get all the rows where the email address is `IN ( yourSelect)`. Or you can use your query as a subquery and join in with the table, with something like `select ... from yourTable inner join (yourSelect) on (...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Inner query gives those `EMAIL_ADDRESS`'s, who have  at least  2 or more different `UI_D`. Then simply joined  these EMAIL_ADDRESS's with whole table.

```
SELECT EMAIL.* FROM EMAIL INNER JOIN (
      select  EMAIL_ADDRESS from EMAIL
      group by  EMAIL_ADDRESS
      having min(UI_D) <> max(UI_D)
) TT
on EMAIL.EMAIL_ADDRESS = TT.EMAIL_ADDRESS
order by EMAIL.EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL.UI_D
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I'm using the count(*) analytic function to provide the count of records with the same address in the internal query, or view.  Then, I've wrapped it with a query that filters for only the rows where the count is > 1.

```
select email_id, email_address from 
        (with email (id, email_address) as
         (select 67890 as id, 'asmith@...' as email_address from dual union all
          select 75236, 'asmith@...' from dual union all
          select 15689, 'bjones@...' from dual union all
          select 56748, 'bjones@...' from dual union all
          select 89523, 'bjones@...' from dual union all
          select 98542, 'cbaker@...' from dual union all
          select 00245, 'cbaker@...' from dual union all
          select 54321, 'unique1@...' from dual union all
          select 65432, 'unique2@...' from dual)
    select to_char(id,'00009') as email_id, email_address,
           count(*) over (partition by email_address) as c
 from email) email_data
 where email_data.c > 1
 order by email_data.email_address;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

select distinct uid, email
from email
order by email;

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to do this with an analytic function:

```
select ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS from 
  (select ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS, count(*) over (partition by EMAIL_ADDRESS) count from EMAIL) 
where count > 1 order by EMAIL_ADDRESS;
```

If you run this query, for example, on the following data:

```
create table EMAIL (ID number primary key, EMAIL_ADDRESS varchar2(255));
insert into EMAIL values (1, 'test@test.de');
insert into EMAIL values (2, 'test@test.de');
insert into EMAIL values (3, 'test2@test.de');
```

The result is:

```
1   test@test.de
2   test@test.de
```